# What is the benefit of using RWMutex instead of Mutex?

Tags: go

I am not sure when to use RWMutex and when to use Mutex.

Do you save resources if you use RWMutex instead of Mutex if you do more reads then writes?

I see some people use Mutex all the time no matter what they do, and some use RWMutex and run these methods:

```
func (rw *RWMutex) Lock()
func (rw *RWMutex) Unlock()
func (rw *RWMutex) RLock()
func (rw *RWMutex) RUnlock()
```

instead of just:

```
func (m *Mutex) Lock()
func (m *Mutex) Unlock()
```

If you save resources, is it that much of a difference that you should use RWMutex if you do more reads then writes?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) (emphasis mine):

> A RWMutex is a reader/writer mutual exclusion lock. *The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer.* The zero value for a RWMutex is an unlocked mutex.

In other words, readers don't have to wait for each other. They only have to wait for writers that are holding the lock.

A sync.RWMutex is thus preferable for data that is mostly read, and the resource that is saved compared to a sync.Mutex is time.

Comment: "If a goroutine holds an RWMutex for reading and another goroutine might call Lock, no goroutine should expect to be able to acquire a read lock until the initial read lock is released. In particular, this prohibits recursive read locking. This is to ensure that the lock eventually becomes available; a blocked Lock call excludes new readers from acquiring the lock."
-These lines from the docs... Can you please elaborate on these?

Comment: @Hardy, essentially it means that it's not okay to "nest" RLock/RUnlock calls. RLock is not guaranteed to be able to proceed immediately, if there is at least one other goroutine that may call Lock (which is pretty much always true, else you wouldn't need the mutex). Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/wdI4kX--GHA

Answer (score 5):

Because a just reading function will not change the file contents, it's fine to allow many readers reading a same file simultaneously to improve the program's efficiency.

A writing activity will change the file content, so it needed to mutually exclusive access otherwise it will cause unexceptable errors.

The key point is to understand what will happen when use a read-write lock. Here is a [blog](https://programmer.ink/think/go-mutex-sync.mutex-and-read-write-lock-sync.rwmutex.html) to explain this:

> 1. Attempting to lock the write lock again when the write lock has been locked will block the current goroutine
> 2. Attempting to lock the read lock again when the write lock is locked will also block the current goroutine
> 3. Attempting to lock the write lock while the read lock is locked will also block the current goroutine
> 4. Attempting to lock the read lock after the read lock has been locked will not block the current goroutine